# Fit Squares of x area in rectangular area of m*n

Tags: geometry

I am looking for a formula to fit squares of fix area (say $a$) into a given area of $M$ x $N$

I have some data with me for instance say $a = 324$

1. 20 squares fit an area of $120^2$
2. 42 squares fit an area of $150^2$

What will be the formula to fit $a = 324$ squares in $M$x$N$

Comment: What do you mean by `fit squares`? $20$ squares of area $324$ each have a total area of $6480$ which is less than half of $120^2 = 14400$.

Comment: I have to put x number of squares in $M$ x $N$ area, in a way that matches the two data sets. Yes it is less than half of $14400$ But if you see the second dataset the total Area is more than half of $150^2$

Comment: Neither set fits with the question at all, which is why I asked that you clarify. Sorry, I can't guess what you really mean to ask. Only *you* know that.

Comment: First data point: Even with $N$ being just a hair under $2\sqrt{324}$ so the rectangle would be just one row of squares, $M$ would be over $22\sqrt{324}$ (22 squares total), and that is the closest you can get to the stated data (just 20 squares). Second data point: If $N$ is just a hair under $2\sqrt{324}$ (a single line of squares), $M$ is over $34\sqrt{324}$, which is not enough (just 34 squares total). If $2\sqrt{324} \le N \lt 3\sqrt{324}$ (two rows of squares), $M$ is over $23\sqrt{324}$, which is too much (2×23 squares). None of the other possible ranges of $N$ or $M$ work, either!

Comment: @progrAmmar: In other words, **your data does not match your question**. It is like you are asking how you can divide 100 by 5 and still get 33. Something is wrong in your question, or in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data makes zero sense, so I shall ignore it.

> What will be the formula to fit [area] a=324 squares in MxN

You can fit
$$\left\lfloor\frac{M}{x}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{N}{x}\right\rfloor$$
squares of size $x$ by $x$ into a rectangle of size $M$ by $N$, where $\lfloor\rfloor$ denotes the *floor* operation (rounding down), and the squares are aligned to the rectangle (not rotated).

If the area of the square is $a$, then $x = \sqrt{a}$. Therefore, the number $n$ of squares of area $a$ that fit, aligned (without rotating), within a rectangle of size $M$ by $N$, is
$$n = \left\lfloor\frac{M}{\sqrt{a}}\right\rfloor\left\lfloor\frac{N}{\sqrt{a}}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: For $M=N=120$ and $\sqrt{324}=18$ your answer would give $n=36$. But the OP said it's $20$ in that case.

Comment: @dxiv: Thanks. True; OP's data makes zero sense. Edited my answer to point that out. However, the question *"how many squares you can fit into a rectangle"* can only be interpreted as a straightforward packing problem, which has exactly one *gotcha*: rounding down the number of squares along each direction, before multiplying them. Perhaps showing this jolts the OP into asking the right question, about their actual problem?

Comment: Yours is a sensible answer, but to a (presumably) different question than the OP asked. Just IMHO it's not worth the effort to second guess what the real question was until the OP bothers to clarify.

Comment: @dxiv: I disagree: I answer the question the OP stated. It is just that the question OP asked does not describe the actual problem they are having. By answering the stated question, anybody else dealing with square packing problems stumbling onto this question will see my answer. I don't really care if I can get OP to understand this solution; many people find questions here via web searches, and my hope is each answer I write will help (or interest) more than one person. Helping just OP is not my cup of tea.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree then. Your answer does actually answer the *title* of the question, and is in fact one sensible interpretation thereof as I already said in my previous comment. However, the first line of your answer `Your data makes zero sense, *so I shall ignore it*` brushes over more than half of the question as actually posted, so claiming that it answers `the question the OP stated` is a bit of a stretch, again IMHO.

Comment: @dxiv: Perhaps it would be better to say the data does not match the question. In particular, everything except the data talks about an $N \times M$ rectangle. Yet, the data only specifies areas. (And I did check: you cannot construct a rectangle with the stated areas that the stated number of squares can fit into.) It is as if the data was copied from a nearby, but unrelated text; a wart of gobbledygook. Readers will just skip the data anyway -- even I assumed, without checking, that it should match the question. That's why I don't think of the data as "more than half the question".

Comment: Hey thanks man, I am sorry I couldn't explain it better, but this will do thanks for the help